# toggling three divs in angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I am looking at toggling between three divs in my angular 4 application. I basically have three divs for the following
Income Statement
Cash Flow Statement
Balance Sheet

If you notice anchor tags within ul - li tag . Clicking on the anchor tag should display the corresponding div. I have set the href to href="javascript:void(0); and trying to toggle based on showTable variable which is set to true by default on the component code. For some reason it doesnt work. Could somebody tell me how can I go about achieving it

```
<div class="card-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills financial-tab" id="financial-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" [ngClass]="showTable ? '' : 'active' " id="sincome-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" aria-controls="table"
                        aria-selected="true" (click)="showTable = !showTable">Income Statement</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="!showTable ? '' : 'active' " id="cash-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" aria-controls="chart"
                        aria-selected="false" (click)="showTable = !showTable">Cash Flow Statement</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="!showTable ? '' : 'active' " id="balance-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" aria-controls="chart"
                        aria-selected="false" (click)="showTable = !showTable">Balance Sheet</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

             <div class="tab-content Financial-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                <!-- Income table -->
                <div  *ngIf="showTable" class="tab-pane fade active show" id="base-strategy--fs-statement" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab" aria-expanded="false">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>2017</th>
                                <th>2018</th>
                                <th>2019</th>
                                <th>2020</th>
                                <th>2021</th>
                              </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>       

                             <tr>
                                <td>Direct premiums written</td>
                                <td>33,150,000</td>
                                <td>33,813,000</td>
                                <td>35,179,045 </td>
                                <td>35,882,626 </td>
                                <td>35,882,626 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Assumed premiums written</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div  *ngIf="showTable" class="tab-pane fade" id="base-strategy--fs-cashflow" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab" aria-expanded="false">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead> 
                         <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>2017</th>
                                <th>2018</th>
                                <th>2019</th>
                                <th>2020</th>
                                <th>2021</th>
                              </tr>
                        </thead>
                         <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="6">Cash flows provided (used) by operating</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Premiums Collected -net of ceded premium</td>
                            <td>33,150,000</td>
                            <td>33,813,000</td>
                            <td>35,179,045 </td>
                            <td>35,882,626 </td>
                            <td>35,882,626 </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Loss and LAE Paid</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                        </tr>
                         </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>  
             <div class="tab-pane fade" id="base-strategy--fs-balancesheet" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab" aria-expanded="false">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>As of the end of the period</th>
                            <th>2017</th>
                            <th>2018</th>
                            <th>2019</th>
                            <th>2020</th>
                            <th>2021</th>
                        </tr> 
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                         <tr>
                            <th colspan="6">Assets</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cash, Cash Equivalents </td>
                            <td>18,387,125</td>
                            <td>33,813,000</td>
                            <td>35,179,045 </td>
                            <td>35,882,626 </td>
                            <td>35,882,626 </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Short Term Investments</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: You're using the same `showTable` field to control all of the divs. Create three different variables like `showIncome`, `showCashFlow`, `showBalanceSheet` and change them independently.

Comment: So do you mean have three Boolean variables in component and when I click on one set that to true and rest two to false . If my understanding is wrong then could you provide me an example

Comment: please check answer provided solution

Comment: let me know it works for you or you need something else

Comment: Yes, you can create three different booleans. I assume that's what you were after. Though the solution provided by @PranayRana is better, as it wouldn't allow two divs to be displayed at the same time.

Comment: updated answer please have as look

Comment: is that worked for you ?? first solution

Answer (score 1):

if you wan to display div based on anchor click and toggle then do as below.

```
displayDivNumber:number;

onAnchorClick(no) {
 this.displayDivNumber = no;
}
```

html with ngSwitch

```
<a (click)= "onAnchorClick(1)"> </a>
<a (click)= "onAnchorClick(2)"> </a>
<a (click)= "onAnchorClick(3)"> </a>

<div [ngSwitch]="displayDivNumber">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="1">Tab content 1</div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="2">Tab content 2</div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="3">Tab content 3</div>
</div>
```

or if need to make visible on/off indivisually then you should try to do as below by creating individual variable for each.

```
displayDiv1:boolean=true;
displayDiv2:boolean=false;
displayDiv3:boolean=false;    
onAnchorClick(no) {
 if(no===1) {
  displayDiv1 = !displayDiv1;
 } else if(no===2) {
  displayDiv2 = !displayDiv2;
 } else if(no===3) {
  displayDiv3 = !displayDiv3;
 }
}
```

html

```
<a (click)= "onAnchorClick(1)"> </a>
<a (click)= "onAnchorClick(2)"> </a>
<a (click)= "onAnchorClick(3)"> </a>

<div [ngSwitch]="displayDivNumber">
      <div *ngIf="displayDiv1">Tab content 1</div>
      <div *ngIf="displayDiv2">Tab content 2</div>
      <div *ngIf="displayDiv3">Tab content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried the second option. While debugging i can see for e.g when i click the onAnchorClick(2) , it hits the correct switch in the method though the div isnt visible. Is it because the first div isnt set to false

Comment: What actually worked for me is  onTabClick(no) {
    if (no === 1) {
      this.showIncomeStatement = true;
      this.showCashFlow = false;
      this.showBalanceSheet = false;
    } else if (no === 2) {
      this.showCashFlow = true;
      this.showIncomeStatement = false;
      this.showBalanceSheet = false;
    } else if (no === 3) {
      this.showBalanceSheet = true;
      this.showCashFlow = false;
      this.showBalanceSheet = false;
    }
  }

Comment: @Tom - then you should try frist option , you dont need to write this much long code ..ngswitch take care on off stuff for you